# How does Minecraft perform lighting?

Tags: opengl, rendering, real-time, lighting, minecraft

The only model I'm familiar with is diffuse lighting but this look way more complicated than that.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Each square has a light level from 15 to 0.  Each level is 20% less than the level above it.  If a square contains a light source it gets the luminosity of that light source, otherwise it gets one less than the brightest neighbor.

Sunlight is special, it suffers no vertical attenuation.

Comment: Just a thought, would adjacent blocks (blocks connected by a corner) be considered neighbors with this algorithm?

Comment: @Ben No diagonal blocks are not neighbors in this calculation.

Comment: Are you sure that Minecraft has nothing to do with deferred shading?

Answer (score 24):

While the answer by Loren is mostly correct, I’d like to add that the [minecraftwiki](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Light) has further information.

Sunlight and moonlight works by essentially making blocks with nothing but air and glass above glow with the current lightness (15 at day, 7 at night and something between at dusk/dawn)

The falloff described by Loren means that level 0 still has 0.8¹⁵·100% = 3.5% lightness (to quote my own edit in the minecraftwiki)

The smooth lighting intruduced with Beta 1.3 works by using the light values of the adjacent blocks to generate a gradient.

Comment: I assume smooth lighting works by taking the adjacent blocks *for each corner*.

Answer (score 2):

The light sources in Minecraft are as listed: Of course, sunlight during a thunderstorm and the nether's light are exceptions to the rule: If the light level is UNDER 7, entities will spawn. These are both over 7, but mobs will spawn because in the nether, it acts as if it is night, and because a thunderstorm changes the "time" of the day, mobs do spawn.

```
Beacon  15
End Portal Block    15
Fire    15
Glowstone   15
Jack o'Lantern  15
Lava    15
Redstone Lamp, when powered 15
Sea Lantern 15
Torch   14
Furnace, when active    13
Glowing Obsidian    12
Nether Portal Block 11
Redstone Ore, when touched  9
Ender Chest 7
Redstone Torch, when on 7
Brewing Stand   1
Brown Mushroom  1
Dragon Egg  1
End Portal block    1
```

Other

```
Sunlight    15
Sunlight, during Rain or Snowfall   12
Sunlight, during a Thunderstorm 10
Moonlight   4
```

(Cited from this website: https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Light#Sources_of_light)